# Code for a Madlibs game, how to store each input instead of only the last input{JAVA}

Tags: java, loops, methods

So basically this is my code below, Asking the user to input a noun or a verb depending on the string, and it does that up until the string is finished, however when it outputs edited string, it outputs the last verb and the last noun inputted by the user. My question is, with this code, is there a way to save each input in its respective place in the string and then move onto the next?
ps: I'm not allowed to use arrays.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MadLibsProject
{
    public static void story()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String noun = "";
        String verb = "";
        String story = "The Little Noun And The Old Noun By Shel Silverstein \nSaid the little boy, "+
        "sometimes I drop my noun. \nSaid the little old man, I verb that too.\nThe little boy whispered, I verb my noun.\n"+
        "I do too, laughed the old noun. \nSaid the little boy, I often cry. \nThe old "+
        "man nodded. So do I. \nBut worst of all, verb the noun, "+
        "it seems grown-ups don’t pay attention to me. \nAnd he felt the warmth of a "+
        "wrinkled old hand. \nI verb what you verb, said the little old noun.";
        String update ="";
        String noun1 = noun;
        String verb1 = verb;
        for(int i =0;i< story.length()-4;i++)
        {
            String madlib = story.substring(i,i+4);
            if("noun".contains(madlib) || ("Noun".contains(madlib)))
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a noun");
                noun = in.next();
                
            }
            
            
            else if("verb".contains(madlib))
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a verb");
                verb = in.next();
                verb1 = verb;
            }
            noun1 = noun;
            verb1 = verb;
            update = store(noun1,verb1);
            
        }
        
        System.out.print(update);
    }
    public static String store(String noun,String verb)
    {   
        // for int i = 0;i < story.length()-4; i++
        // madlib = story.substring(i,i+4)
        // noun.contains mmadlib
        String story = "The Little "+ noun+" And The Old "+noun+" By Shel Silverstein \nSaid the little boy, "+
        "sometimes I drop my "+noun+". \nSaid the little old man, I "+verb+" that too.\nThe little boy whispered, I "+verb+" my "+noun+".\n"+
        "I do too, laughed the old "+noun+". \nSaid the little boy, I often cry. \nThe old "+
        "man nodded. So do I. \nBut worst of all, "+verb+" the "+noun+", "+
        "it seems grown-ups don’t pay attention to me. \nAnd he felt the warmth of a "+
        "wrinkled old hand. \nI "+verb+"  what you "+verb+", said the little old "+noun+".";
        return story;
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        story();
        
        
    }
```

> This is my output right now:
> inputs:
> Please enter a noun
> noun1
> Please enter a noun
> noun2
> Please enter a noun
> noun3
> Please enter a verb
> verb1
> Please enter a verb
> verb2
> Please enter a noun
> noun4
> Please enter a noun
> noun5
> Please enter a verb
> verb3
> Please enter a noun
> noun6
> Please enter a verb
> verb4
> Please enter a verb
> verb5
> Please enter a noun
> noun7
> OUTPUT:
> The Little noun7 And The Old noun7 By Shel Silverstein
> Said the little boy, sometimes I drop my noun7.
> Said the little old man, I verb5 that too.
> The little boy whispered, I verb5 my noun7.
> I do too, laughed the old noun7.
> Said the little boy, I often cry.
> The old man nodded. So do I.
> But worst of all, verb5 the noun7, it seems grown-ups don’t pay attention to me.
> And he felt the warmth of a wrinkled old hand.
> I verb5  what you verb5, said the little old noun7.`your text`

Comment: Use a `java.util.List` to store nouns and verbs.  Keep track of the index of the `List` and go through the list when you encounter a noun or a verb.  The `String` `equalsIgnoreCase` method will simplify your comparisons.

Answer (score -2):

> *"... is there a way to save each input in its respective place in the string and then move onto the next? ..."*

Create a code for the *nouns* and *verbs*, for example, *"%noun%"*, or *"=verb="*.

```
The Little =Noun= And The Old =Noun= By Shel Silverstein \nSaid the little boy, 
sometimes I drop my =noun=. \nSaid the little old man, I =verb= that too.\nThe little boy whispered, I =verb= my =noun=.\n
I do too, laughed the old =noun=. \nSaid the little boy, I often cry. \nThe old 
man nodded. So do I. \nBut worst of all, =verb= the =noun=, 
it seems grown-ups don’t pay attention to me. \nAnd he felt the warmth of a 
wrinkled old hand. \nI =verb= what you =verb=, said the little old =noun=.
```

Then, utilize the *[StringBuilder#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int))* method to add the values.

Here is an example.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(story);
String t;
for (int i = 0, j, n = s.length(); i < n; i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == '=') {
        j = s.indexOf("=", i + 1);
        System.out.printf("Please enter a %s%n", s.substring(i + 1, j));
        s.replace(i, j + 1, t = in.next());
        i += t.length();
        n = s.length();
    }
```

Additionally, you may want to check if it's uppercase.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(story);
String t;
boolean u;
for (int i = 0, j, n = s.length(); i < n; i++)
    if (s.charAt(i) == '=') {
        j = s.indexOf("=", i + 1);
        t = s.substring(i + 1, j);
        u = Character.isUpperCase(t.charAt(0));
        System.out.printf("Please enter a %s%n", t.toLowerCase());
        t = in.next();
        if (u) t = t.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + t.substring(1);
        s.replace(i, j + 1, t);
        i += t.length();
        n = s.length();
    }
```